# Increase level zoom

Tags: product, magento-1.8, module, zoom

How could I increase the level zoom on this store?

https://comerciomix.com.br/100-canecas-de-acrilico-de-400-ml-sem-personalizac-o.html

I have the options on backend (we use Prozoom module) to choice the width and height but we want to increase the level, or scale, of the zoom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PT** - Vê se funciona com você meu módulo, é possível alterar as dimensões etc

**EN** - See if it works with you the my module, you can change the dimensions etc.
[http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dexxtz-product-zoom.html](http://bit.ly/dexxtz-product-zoom)

Comment: Was very good in your store, to have great images =D

Answer (score 0):

now you use image 1200x1200 px. Try to change settings for Zoom module

Comment: thanks!! I do it on zoom module config or in the magento system?

Comment: and, I need to put a smaller value?

Comment: bigger. But anyway you can play with settings to understand them

Comment: where I found this values?